# How to package server side JavaScript for Node

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webpack, tree-shaking

I have been using webpack to build a server side app using express. This code is harder to debug since I don't have the immediate comfort of a web browser and if I use something like VS Code to debug, it won't accept breakpoints inside request handlers when using source maps. Besides it takes no time to compile if I just stick to Node compatible JS and skip all transpiling and whatnot. Further, if I use treeshaking, I can reduce the size, but what is the point of that when it is running on the server (no client will ever download it).

My point is that I don't see why one would want to create a bundle of server side code if the server don't have any issues with memory or other limiting factors. It's easier to read, takes no time to compile and is easier to debug.

So a question. Is it ok to have the server app as an npm package and deploy that? Is that what is common or what do people do?

Answer (score 0):

The project my team works on is a TypeScript monorepo that includes a web application and server-side daemon processes. We use webpack for producing build artefacts for all targets.

I've read some posts saying there's no point using webpack server-side because it was designed for web (obv), and I can understand that point of view.

However, even if our code was JavaScript and didn't require any transpiling, we'd still use webpack for the server-side. I want a single, minimal set of files and no node modules to deploy to the servers.

Size itself doesn't matter that much for server side (though every bit helps), but running 'yarn install' on servers is out of the question IMO.